# Use helper methods inside a locales file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, gitorious

I'm trying to get Gitorious up and running using Rails 3, but I've come a cross a problem.

I've this line in the view.

```
<p><%= t("views.commits.message").call(self, tree_path(@commit.id)) %></p>
```

The corresponding locales line looks like this [`config/locales/en.rb`]

```
 :message => lambda { |this, path| "This is the initial commit in this repository, " +
      this.link_to( "browse the initial tree state", path ) + "." }
```

The problem here is that the lambda method isn't being called using `#call`in the view, it's being called by someone else, which means that `this` isn't `self` that is  being passed to it.

`this` contains `views.commits.message` and `path` contains `{:rescue_format=>:html}`.
The Gitorious team has used this approach all over the application, which means that I can't just move the logic into a helper method without taking a day of form work.

I did some research and found [this](http://gitorious.lighthouseapp.com/projects/53751/tickets/15-viewing-some-commits-throw-an-error) thread about the exact line.

This was the answare to the problem.

> This seems to indicate you have the i18n gem installed on your system; this gem is incompatible with Gitorious. Uninstalling it with Rubygems should resolve the issue.

I've tried to uninstall `i18n`, but running `bundle install` just installs it again.

How should I solve this problem without refactor the 700 line locales file?

Comment: Are you able to change the view so that it makes a more "standard" I18n.t call? Passing in the current context to a translation just so that it can use link_to is kinda crazy!

Comment: Changing all `t`-calls for the application isn't realistic.

Comment: Not thinking **all** `t` calls, just the one with a link in it. Could be as simple as this : 

    <%= t :'views.commits.message, :link => link_to(t(:'views.commits.link'), :path => tree_path(@commit.id))) %>

and then in your locale file :

    en:
      views:
        commits:
          message: "This is the initial commit in this repository, %{link}"
          link: "browse the initial tree state"

Comment: I sorta agree with @tigrish. In my opinion, link_to should be called from the view since it's a view helper and you should call t again for the string to pass to t. Example:

`<p><%= t "views.commits.message" %><%= link_to t("views.commits.browse"), tree_path(@commit.id) %></p>`

Doing things the right way is worth the time investment. Think about a year from now if you had to change something. It would take you an hour to even recognize what was going on in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, how to break up complex nested pieces of text.

Using markdown to simplify it

```
This is the initial commit in this repository
[browse the initial tree state](http://example.com/some/path)
.
```

Perhaps in Chinese you'd instead say

```
这是第一个提交在这个知识库
[看初始状态](http://example.com/some/path)
。
```

We have to consider 3 things;

1. The outer text
2. The link text
3. The order and position of these two

If the position of the link relative to the text doesnt need to change, then @WattsInABox correct.

```
views.commits.message: "This is the initial commit in this repository"
views.commits.browse:  "browse the initial tree state"
```

We then just compose

```
<p>
  <%= t "views.commits.message" %>
  <%= link_to t("views.commits.browse"), tree_path(@commit.id) %>
  .
</p>
```

But sometimes the order and position does matter,
in which case we can try to be more clever.

```
views.commits.message: "This is the initial commit in this repository %{link}"
views.commits.browse:  "browse the initial tree state"
```

Then we can interpolate the link in the right place

```
<p>
  <%= t "views.commits.message", link: link_to(t("views.commits.browse"), tree_path(@commit.id)) %>
</p>
```

Comment: I know this question is a year old, but it felt worth answering.